# Can mongoDB allow connections only from a specific IP?

Tags: mongodb, security

I want to allow connections to mongoDB only from a specific IP.

How to do it?

The bind_ip can not help me:
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip

Comment: Why is bind_ip not helpful? You might want to use authentication with username and password instead.

Comment: Secure the network using operating system and networking options, not using options within MongoDB. Additionally, you should use authentication and authorization if you are worried about access control.

Comment: Is only authentication with user name and password enough for secured access to MongoDB?
According to the link below I need to create a different user for each customer:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/security/#password-hashing-security

Answer (score 1):

Mongo itself doesn't provide any facility for this as far as I can tell.   You will need to restrict the incoming IP addresses at the firewall, either on the machine itself or the network's firewall depending on your setup.